# Is it possible to restore my lost photos from memory card?

Tags: data-recovery

My memory card was found yesterday, but I found the photos stored in it have gone, is it possible to restore them back? If so, how? Please recommend some affordable program and works for my memory card, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Photorec

This software is part of the [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk] suite, specifically designed to recover images from a partially overwritten or otherwise damaged drive.

There is an extremely helpful step-by-step guide written by the makers of PhotoRec which I recommend you follow:

- [PhotoRec Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step)

In case you have Ubuntu installed you can run PhotoRec in a terminal after installation of the TestDisk suite but you can also do so from a live system as further elaborated in my answer to the following questions:

- [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

We should try to recover our files from an image we created from the memory card by running the following command (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296109/need-to-recover-data-from-a-data-hard-disk-that-i-used-testdisk-on-in-my-attempt)) in a terminal:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=/home/<user>/<path>/rescue.dd
```

Replace `sdX` with the appropriate value for your memory card, and replace `/<user>/<path>/` with your path for the rescued file. **Be extra careful to get the command right, dd is an advanced tool!**

We can then recover files from this image with:

```
photorec rescue.dd
```

Comment: In addition to the $30 you will have to pay - vibosoft will not run on Ubuntu...

Comment: testdisk resp. photorec (built-in in testdisk) is best solution you can have here suiting to your question !

Comment: This is my personal experience; I accidentally deleted all 300+ pictures and was able to recover them. I was able to use the software to recover my pictures and I went ahead and paid for it too! Let me tell you, it was worth it! Those were the only pictures of my son's graduation and the small fee I didn't mind paying since someone bothered to write such a good piece of software that could save my memories!

Answer (score 0):

Deleted or lost files can sometimes be recovered from failed or formatted drives and partitions, CD-ROMs and memory cards using the **free/libre** software available in the Ubuntu repositories.