# Recover external drive after faulty clone

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd, clone, disk-image

I was trying to restore my formatted D partition using `testdisk` by following the first answer in this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296109/need-to-recover-data-from-a-data-hard-disk-that-i-used-testdisk-on-in-my-attempt)

In one of the steps I was supposed to **clone** my D drive to an external HDD and did so overnight.  When it finished I noticed that the 1 TB external hard was all wiped out and replaced by my formatted D drive .

I tried to restore the partition of the external hard using `testdisk`, `gparted` and `gpart` but they said they couldn't find anything.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `dd if=/dev/XdY of=/dev/AdB` and our internal HDD was larger then *the amount of data* stored on your external drive, you've lost everything on the external hard drive.  (Depending on the size of the internal HDD and *the amount of data that the external HDD contained*, your chances of recovery vary from 0% to an unknown %…)

As you're talking about a D-drive, I suppose you were following very advanced Linux instructions to the letter and that is why the original post mentions:

> It is critical at this point to get the `dd` command correctly. If you gave the wrong entry to `of=` you may damage all data that had existed there.

To clone a drive to *an image file* the correct form of the command would have been:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/ubuntu/D-Drive.img
```

As a side note, `dd` is also know as **d**isk **d**estroyer in the Linux community as it can do extremely powerful things, but also do extremely disastrous things if used wrongly.

Comment: **:-)**  Thanks...  I asked you to delete yours as I'm not a moderator on this site, just a reviewer and editor so I cannot delete other people's comments.  **;-)**  Let's leave it this way: clean enough!