# Testdisk / Recphoto freezes the system

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, crash

I use photorec of testdisk, and when the program is about to end the scan, and start writing in the recovery directory, the computer freezes and I have to reset everything. I make this data recovery through ubuntu live cd, and the program works on a compromised internal hard disk partition while I'm on the other along with the recovery directory. How do I proceed in order not to paralyze the computer when the program begins to write the contents recovered? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the problem in the compromised partition  hardware or software?

Comment: I think it is in software; fsck had tracked corrupted attributes in f.s., now the f.s. is reset correctly to ext4, the OS is departed, nevertheless recphoto recovered a lot of elements, but I cannot see them because of the mentioned problem (along with the recovery directory I stay on the other partition) Can I copy the partition on a pen-drive? Then I could test recphoto on that device; will the pen copy maintain *exactly* the same bits of the disk?

Comment: We can't recover data on the same drive. Please attach an external drive to hold recovered files. Alternatively you can also [create an image of the corrupted partition](http://askubuntu.com/a/296365/3940) to let PhotoRec recover from this image.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it is impossible, infact I made a clone on a pen with Clonezilla and the program worked correctly.

Comment: Same issue here. Using an external hard drive to receive the data (while using `photorec`). My guess is that some files might be too big to be handled by the liveusb booted OS (which has to hold everything in RAM, hasn't it?)